# How do I remove values found in one ArrayList from another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
values.add(9);
```

That's one, here's the other:

```
ArrayList<Integer> values2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++){
        values2.add(j);
    }
```

How can I compare the two and remove 9 from the second ArrayList?
I tried using a foreach statement but I kept getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

This had been a head-peck for some hours now and I appreciate any help you can offer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use

```
values2.removeAll(values);
```

From the Javadoc for the `Collection` interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) -

> **boolean removeAll(Collection c)**
>
> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in
>   the specified collection (optional operation). After this call
>   returns, this collection will contain no elements in common with the
>   specified collection.

Comment: Gonna slam my head against a brick wall now, thanks bro. My profile picture is so relevant right now.

Comment: @MattKnowles Happens to the best of us. As long as the docs are your first source, you'll be fine in the long run.